# Making the root for relative paths consistent between Eclipse and javac

Tags: java, path, compilation

I'm testing a project where I'm running a server application on one computer and a client application on another. On the computer I'm using for developing I'm running the application from Eclipse. On the other computer I've just been using javac to compile and then running from the terminal.

I've noticed that for relative paths, Eclipse resolves the path starting from the root directory of the project (the directory containing the src folder, the bin folder, etc).

Meanwhile with your normal javac compilation, it resolves paths starting from wherever the .class file is, which isn't in the root directory.

This inconsistency is making it difficult to load images since it's looking for them in different places on each side. Is there a way I can make this consistent, perhaps by adding more arguments to javac?

Comment: It's normally the path that you're in when you start the java process I think, not relative to the actual files you're running. You can probably change the path Eclipse is using in its run configuration for your project if you really want to change that, or you can change where you start java from on your client.

Comment: Ah, yup. Changing where I started java from on the client fixed the issue. Thanks.